# Calculating Average in Google doc based on values in other columns

Tags: average, google-docs

[image]

I want to calculate the average marks obtained by students of set1, set2 and set3. Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `averageif`. If your two columns are A and B, and you have 10 rows:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A1:A10,"Set 1",B1:B10)
=AVERAGEIF(A1:A10,"Set 2",B1:B10)
=AVERAGEIF(A1:A10,"Set 3",B1:B10)
```

Comment: I used Countif in the formula and it works thanks @such                                            
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A="Set 1"),B1:B)/COUNTIF(A1:A,"=Set 1")

Comment: You're right. On a second thought I realised that there is another function that fits the question even better: `averageif`